# Can't activate sheet: "Object Required"

Tags: excel, vba

I got an `error 424: Object Required`.

It's a very simple script, I can't see where I'm going wrong.

The strange thing is, this worked many times before. I am only getting these errors today.

I rename sheet one as "All Data". Then add another sheet and rename it "List".

The error happens when I try to activate the "List" sheet. `Object Required`. I guess it can't detect the new sheet? Where am I going wrong? As I said this worked 100 times before.

```
    Sheets(1).Select
    Sheets(1).Name = "All Data"

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets(2).Select
    Sheets(2).Name = "List"
    List.Activate ' error happens here
```

I have also tried `List.Select` instead of Activate. Same error.

Comment: Did you mean `Sheets("List").Activate`?

Answer (score 3):

If `List` is not the VBA name of a sheet it has to be defined:

```
Dim List As Worksheet
Set List = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List")
```

or make sure the VBA name of that sheet is actually changed to `List` in the properties window of the VBA editor.

- `List.Activate` activates a sheet which VBA name is `List`
- `Worksheets("List").Activate` activates a sheet which tab name is `List`

note that these 2 naming systems are completely independent.

You might benefit from reading
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

```
Worksheet(1).Name = "All Data"
Worksheet.Add(After:=Worksheet("All Data")).Name = "List"
Worksheet("List").Activate ' don't use activate! see link above
```

or

```
Worksheet(1).Name = "All Data"

Dim List As Worksheet
Set List = Worksheet.Add(After:=Worksheet("All Data"))
List.Name = "List"
List.Activate ' don't use activate! see link above
```

Don't mix `Sheets` with `Worksheets` they count differently. `Sheets` contains all types of sheets like worksheets, chart sheets, etc. but `Worksheets` only contains worksheets.

If you have 2 worksheets and 1 chart sheet:

- `Worksheets.Count` is `2` but
- `Sheets.Count` is `3`.